Command left and right shortcuts not working on Xcode anymore
I started Xcode and now whenever I try to use the shortcuts for end and beginning of text, Command + right or Command + left, the computer makes a beeping noise and nothing happens. There isn't an issue with these commands in any other application. I tried to restart without restarting applications but no luck. I am on Ventura 13.7.1 and Xcode 15.2. Another thing to not is that Shift+command+right and left don't work either in Xcode.

Also, the keyboard bindings are unchanged.
